# How to prevent so many merges (workflow issue)

Tags: mercurial

#### Context:

- 7 devs
- 1 product
- 3 branches:

  - Version 3.6 (stable)
  - Version 3.7 (stable)
  - Master (dev)

#### Rules & Policies in place:

- Any fix made in an earlier version must be merged in all future versions.
- Integration is continuous: if you fix something in 3.6, you must integrate and test in 3.7 and in master before you push.
- When possible, rebase your work before you commit so that stuff you committed two days ago locally will actually be put back on top. I know this is a matter of preference and has pros and cons, but this is what we like best as a team.

#### Our problem:

We have too many *useless* merge operations to do. Here is a scenario:

Normal integration work:

- Joe and Bill work on two different fixes that go in 3.6.
- Joe is done, he pulls (and rebases)
- Joe tests one last time in his 3.6 branch
- Joe switches to 3.7 and merges 3.6 - **merge 1**
- Joe tests again, this time in the context of 3.7
- Joe switches to 3.8 and merges 3.7 - **merge 2**
- Joe tests again, this time in the context of 3.8
- Joe is ready to push
- Bill did pretty much the same thing but pushed right after Joe pulled
- Joe tries to push but the operation fails because it would create a new head

Painful (useless) merges:

- Joe pulls, he gets stuff from Bill in 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8
- Joe updates to 3.6 and merges changes he received from the pull - **merge 3**
- Joe updates to 3.7 and merges changes he received from the pull - **merge 4**
- Joe still in 3.7 merges 3.6 - **merge 5**
- Joe updates to 3.8 and merges changes he received from the pull - **merge 6**
- Joe still in 3.8 merges 3.7 - **merge 7**
- Joe tries to push and prays that nobody pushed something to 3.6 in the meantime.

We are thinking of writing an extension (or batch or program) to automatically merge this kind of situation. So when Joe finds out that he cannot push, he would just run `MergeUpAutomagically`. But before we try to fix this, I want to make sure we are using the right workflow.

Comment: I believe this would be better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Your problem seems to be the long time between pushes. Also, doesn't `MergeUpAutomagically` mean you push untested code to a stable branch? If you add tests the extra merges are no longer useless :-)

Comment: No, `MergeUpAutomagically` would not be used to perform the normal integration work, only to re-merge if the first push operation failed. The program would merge and continue if there are no merge conflicts which is what happens in most cases. In case of a merge conflict the program would abort and report an error indicating that a meaningful (manual) merge is necessary.

Comment: Since you have Joe test in 3.7 and 3.8, whether or not he has conflicts, I'm guessing you are worried about introducing ('silent') issues from merging. You are still prone to that at the point you would want to run MergeUpAutomagically though, Bill's changes could introduce a bug with Joe's code, without conflicting, in the same way that Joe's code could break Master without conflicting.

Comment: With my team though we wouldn't test Joe's code in 3.7/3.8/master, unless the merge was particularly complex. Instead we insist on always writing unit tests for new code, and rely on those to catch issues introduced from merges. Although, admittedly, our chances of catching merge issues then are directly reliant on how much the unit tests cover.

Comment: Why do you wait to do the 3.7 and 3.8 merges before pushing 3.6 ?

Comment: @Kindread, about your first two comments: We perform smoke tests in each branch; not complete functional tests. We too rely heavily on automated unit tests. In some cases, the integration work is not simple. For instance a class that exists in 3.6 may not exit in 3.7 anymore.

Comment: @Kindread, about your 3rd comment. We want to push everything at once because if Joe pushes in 3.6 only and plans to pull these commits in 3.7 to integrate, then another dev might unwillingly pull those unintegrated commits. That dev would be forced to do Joe's integration work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you are using named branches in same clones.

I find it easier to use a different clone for each version (releases, devs), where each clone contains a named branch related to the version (and also changesets from the older branches). We have "official" clones where we synchronize (pulls and pushes).

Advantages:

- No need to "switch" by doing hg updates (in my situation I use Eclipse instances with a different work space for each project). I used to work with named branches in same clones but found it confusing.
- Easier to see where the changesets come from (from which named branches-versions). Also, if someone pushes from a higher version to an older one by mistake, it is easy to spot.
- Synchronization is more "atomic". We pull and push for each "official" clone-named-branch, then pull between "official" named branches (from older to newer). 
  In your situation, maybe Bill pushed before Joe, but had only time to do it in 3.6 and Joe realized that before synchronizing to higher versions (not sure it would help in your situation). Also, maybe it is not necessary to synchronize the "dev" branches as often as the "releases".

Comment: In fact we do use one clone-per-branch locally on our PCs but just one central repository. That does not change the of merge operations in my scenario. If you replace "Joe updates to…" to "Joe changes his directory to..." then you get the same end result.

Comment: About your 3rd point, we don't want to do that because if Joe pushes in 3.6 and plans to pull these commits in 3.7 to integrate, then another dev might be forced to do that integration work when he wants to merge his own work from 3.6 and unwillingly pulls Joe's unintegrated commits. This produces less merge operations but creates cases where one dev has to integrate to work of another dev.